# mysql: create view with two differents tables

Tags: mysql, sql, listview, view, phpmyadmin

I want to create a view in mysql with two differents tables. I tried a lot but i wasnt able to get my wished result. I need your help. 
Thank you

Table Syntax:

**video**
ID
name
desc

**channel**
ID
name
desc

Expected Result:

Type gives the result that the row comes from videos or channel

**result_main**
ID
name
desc
type

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `ON`.

Comment: yes but how to use?

Comment: Why do you want a view?

Comment: you can tell me an alternative

Comment: Hi, to help you better, you should show us what you have already tried (i.e: SQL sentence that failed, otherwise a screen capture of the software you are using to create the view, on the same page that it failed).